# Select a substring from string

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a string as follows:

```
string str = "abcdefgh"
```

and I would like to reduce the size to only two chars - so the output would be:

```
str = "ab"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the methods available in the `String` class?

Comment: That's not Trimming, it's Selecting.

Comment: +10 @ Jon for actually motivating people to look at MSDN or there Object Browser, even intellisence in this case...

Answer (score 2):

```
string str = "abcdefgh";
var s = str.Substring(0, 2);
```

Or another solution is to write Your Own extension method (that would check if string longer than expected substring and avoid the exception as [athoik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1093668/athoik) has noticed) and do this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var str = "asdfasd";
        var trimmed = str.MySubString(2);
        Console.WriteLine(trimmed);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }


}
public static class Helper
{
    public static string MySubString(this String value, int length)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Length >= length
        ? value.Substring(0, length)
        : value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

string sub = str.Substring(0, 2);

Comment: When length of str is less than 2 you get an exception

Answer (score 0):

```
    string substr =  str.substring(0,2)
```

or

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.toString(0,2);
```